# Ошибка в mysql_query

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста где здесь ошибка:

```
mysql_query('INSERT INTO startpoke(name_poke,img,life,atk,def,exp,type) VALUES("'.$_GET['name_poke'].','$img','$life','$atk','$def','$exp','$type'")')     or die(mysql_error());
```

А то как я не крутил, постоянно ошибка! Заранее спасибо =)

Comment: Какая ошибка-то хоть? Видимо ругается на двойные кавычки.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in C:\xampp\htdocs\style\register.php on line 46 такая

Comment: Так вы неправильно убрали двойные кавычки. Их не надо убирить, их надо переставлять.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO startpoke(name_poke,img,life,atk,def,exp,type) VALUES('".$_GET['name_poke']."','".$img."','".$life."','".$atk."','".$def."','".$exp."','".$type."');")     or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Работает =)

Comment: phpDesigner 7 и ошибки будут видны заранее)

Comment: phpDesigner неплох, но $100 за лицензию - это слишком.

Answer (score 0):

А так?

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO startpoke(name_poke,img,life,atk,def,exp,type) VALUES('.$_GET['name_poke'].','$img','$life','$atk','$def','$exp','$type')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Рarse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in C:\xampp\htdocs\style\register.php on line 46 теперь такая ошибка =)

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO startpoke(`name_poke`,`img`,`life`,`atk`,`def`,`exp`,`type`) VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name_poke'])."','$img','$life','$atk','$def','$exp','$type')")
```